# Reset row_factory attribute of an Python sqlite3 object

Tags: python, sqlite

How can I reset the "row_factory" attribute of an sqlite3 connection object after setting it to "sqlite3.Row"? For instance:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("db.dat", isolation_level=None)
con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
cur = con.execute("insert into test1 (name, last) values (?, ?)", ("John","doe"))
cur = con.execute("insert into test1 (name, last) values (?, ?)", ("Liz","doe"))
cur.execute("select * from test1")
cur.fetchone() # gets {'name':'john', 'last':'doe'}

# Now I want to get a tuple when calling fetchone
con.row_factory = None
cur.fetchone() #Throw error
delattrib(con, "row_factory") # causes segmentation fault on Windows
```

I can't find an answer anywhere and the only solution (other than casting the dictionary) is to reopen the db connection. I read the documentation for the sqlite3 module, but it doesn't mention anything to reset the attribute back to its default state.

Thank you

Comment: What error does it throw? Setting it to None worked for me.

Comment: You could change the row_factory on the cursor object to change it during a response, or just cast the Row object to a tuple if you want a tuple out of the sqlite3.Row engine.

Comment: Changing it in the cursor worked. The documentation for the module didn't list row_factory as a method of the cursor only of the connection object so I didn't try that :S. Thank you both.